# Триггер и сценарий для опроса сайта. Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Мне необходимо во время понять, что сайт недоступен. Я сформировал сценарий и триггер по стандартному мануалу на сайте, но стало понятно, что сайт периодически перезагружается, следовательно пропадает верстка и срабатывает триггер.

Каким образом я могу изменить структуру сценария или триггера, чтобы он срабатывал не сразу, а после 10 минут отсутствия связи.
Прилагаю код триггера, который я попробовал сделать, но он все равно ругается каждый раз при перезагрузке.

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http://example.ru/].last(10m)}>0 and 
{Zabbix server:web.test.error[http://example.ru/].strlen()}>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь можно посмотреть доступные функции для триггеров - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/ru/manual/appendix/triggers/functions

Дальше.
Например для `Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http://vsks.ru/]`
Можно взять функцию **min**. Будет выглядеть так:

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http://vsks.ru/].min(10m)}>0
```

Т.е. для `web.test.fail` нормальное значение равно 0, а значение больше 0, это шаг проверки на котором произошла ошибка.
Тогда `min(10m)}>0` сработает тогда, когда минимальное значение будет больше 0 в течении 10 минут.
Здесь следует учитывать, что если сайт будет постоянно переходить между состояниями доступен\не доступен, этот триггер не сработает.

Второй вариант.
Использовать функцию **count**

```
{Zabbix server:web.test.fail[http://vsks.ru/].count(10m,0,ne)}>6
```

Здесь нужно учитывать переодичность проверки. предположим - 1 раз в минуту.
Сработает когда за последних 10 минут будет больше 6 значений, отличных от 0.